# Problema al pasar datos de un jsp a un servlet JAVA

Tags: java, postgresql, jsp

Buenas amigos mi problema , la idea es hacer una consulta sql con el valor que tiene el input que se llama CODD, yo tengo el servlet listo pero yo intento pasar los datos por href, pero al capturar el valor del input en el link me da un null, y también probé la otra manera creando input tipo submit y al momento de hacer clic sobre un botton de esos de accionan los 3 botones que tengo creados, podrían ayudarme, aquí dejo el fragmento de código, no se si es que estoy obteniendo de la manera incorrecta el valor escrito en el input pero e intentado varias formas y ninguna me ha dado resultado, soy nuevo en esto del java. muchas gracias de antemano.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*"%>
<%@page import="UsuarioBEANS.Usuario"%>

<%
                        String id ="";
                        String iduser = "";
                        String pass ="";
                        String nomb="";
                        String cargo= "";
                        String email="";
                        String Cel="";
                        if (request.getAttribute("lista")!=null){
                      ArrayList<Usuario> lista=
                     (ArrayList<Usuario>)request.getAttribute("lista");
                      for(int i=0;i<lista.size();i++){
                      Usuario u=lista.get(i);
                      
                         id = u.getId();
                         iduser = u.getId_user();
                         pass = u.getPass();
                         nomb=u.getNombres();
                         cargo= u.getCargo();
                         email=u.getEmail();
                         Cel=u.getCelular();
                      }
                      }
                                                   
                 %>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <h1 align="center">Usuarios</h1>
              <form action="ServletManto">   
            <table border="1" height="50"  align="center">
                
                
                                      
                       <td>
                           <input type="text" name="CODD">
                       </td>
                       
                        <td>
                          <a href="ServletManto?accion=eliminar&CODD=<%=request.getParameter("CODD")%>">
                         Eliminar
                         </a>
                     </td>
                      
                       
                       <td>
                           <input type="hidden" name="accion" value="cargarEdicion" >
                        <input type="submit" name="btn1" value="B">
                        
                     </td>
                     
                     <td>
                          <input type="hidden" name="accion" value="eliminar" >
                        <input type="submit" name="btn2" value="-">
                       
                     </td>
                     
                     <td>
                          <input type="hidden" name="accion" value="insertar">
                         <input type="submit" name="btn3" value="+">
                         
                    </td>

                  
            </table>
           </form>
           
          
            <table border="0" width="300" align="center">

                 <tr>                     
                     
                    <td>ID Usuario</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="txtidUser" value="<%=iduser%>"</td>
                    <td><input type="hidden" name="id" value="<%=id%>"</td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td>Password</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="txtPass"value="<%=pass%>"></td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td>Nombres</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="txtNom" value="<%=nomb%>"></td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td>Cargo</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="txtCargo" value="<%=cargo%>"></td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td>Email</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="txtEmail" value="<%=email%>"></td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td>Celular</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="txtCelular" value="<%=Cel%>"></td>
 
                    </tr>     
              
                
            </table>
      
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la URL con la que accedes por primera vez a ese JSP? (antes de darle al botón de borrar)

Comment: http://localhost:8080/ConexionServlet/modelo1.jsp es esta amigo solo corro el jsp

Comment: Por lo que veo entonces la primera vez que entres a ese jsp, si no has puesto parámetros en la url del JSP, hará que `<%=request.getParameter("CODD")%>` escriba null en la url que estás tratando de construir para el botón de eliminar no?

Comment: amigo, lo que yo quiero es enviar lo que tiene el input que tiene de nombre CODD, por la url para asi luego accionar, entonces no se si lo estoy haciendo mal o como seria para que funcione, poruqe intente colocando input tipe submit pero si coloco uno solo funciona perfectamente, pero al colocar dos o mas , al precionar clic sobre uno el ejecuta la accion sobre los 3

Comment: Para hacer eso lo tienes que resolver por Javascript no con JSP. Lo que  tienes que hacer es un evento que cuando tu input cambie de valor (porque el usuario haya escrito algo) la URL de tu enlace de borrar cambie también. Inténtalo de esta manera y si te atascas pega lo que hayas hecho y tratamos de dejarlo fino.

Comment: vale, muchas gracias no sabia pero ya enseguida me pongo a consultar sobre el tema, si conoces alguna guia o sabes como hacerlo me ayudarias mucho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según lo hablado en los comentarios, esto lo puedes resolver con JavaScript. Para ello tienes que definir un listener para el evento onchange del input que tiene CODD.

Te voy a poner el ejemplo usando jQuery aunque lo podrías adaptar a JavaScript si no puedes usar jQuery por alguna razón.

En primer lugar te recomendaría poner un id al botón de eliminar para luego poder encontrarlo facilmente:

```
<a id="botonEliminar" href="javascript:void(0);">Eliminar</a>
```

Fíjate que he añadido el id botonEliminar y he quitado el contenido del href y le he puesto javascript:void(0) para deshabilitar su funcionalidad.

Ahora ya puedes definir tu listener:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("input[name=CODD]").change(function() {
        var codd = $("input[name=CODD]").val();
        var url; 
        if (codd) {
           url = "ServletManto?accion=eliminar&CODD=" + codd;
        } else {
           url = "javascript:void(0);";           
        }
        $("#botonEliminar").attr("href", url); 
    });
});
</script>
```

De esta manera puedes capturar el momento en el que ese input cambie de valor al pulsar una tecla, e ir cambiando la URL del botonEliminar con lo que el usuario vaya escribiendo. Si el usuario borra el campo totalmente, se volverá a deshabilitar el enlace.

Esto lo puedes modificar para que no aparezca el botón, aparezca disabled, o lo que necesites.

No te olvides de incluir jQuery en tu JSP para que esto te funcione.

EDIT: Para incluir la librería de jQuery lo puedes hacer de varias maneras. Voy a suponer que lo estás haciendo para un ejercicio, por lo que podrías incluirlo escribiendo una etiqueta script de esta manera:

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Si esto fuese para un proyecto que tuvieses que poner en producción te deberías preguntar si es preferible que albergues la librería en tu host o si prefieres que la albergue algún tipo de CDN como es el caso que te he pegado.

Respecto a donde ponerlo, efectivamente lo puedes poner en casi cualquier sitio, pero según donde lo pongas la carga de la página se puede efectuar de una forma u otra. Más información aquí: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-should-i-put-script-tags-in-html-markup

El fragmento de jQuery que te he pasado previamente se ejecutará cuando el DOM de la página web esté cargado completamente en el navegador.

Comment: amigo, para serte sincero no se como inlcuir jquery y en que parte del codigo colocar la funcion, segun logro entender donde coloque la funcion no importa pero aun asi no se como incluir el jquery, estoy buscando asesoria, como podriamos contactarnos

Comment: @Bryhanrios He editado la respuesta para incluir lo que preguntas sobre la inclusión de jQuery